# How to add email addresses from a message to a textbox?

Tags: php, html, email

I'm making a webpage to send a list of email addresses to each user. I have a script called `add_book.php` to allow me to input a list of email addresses in the message like this:

[image: http://oi57.tinypic.com/ra2nhw.jpg]

I want to output a list of email addresses to input each of them in the textbox include with a comma when I click on the button to allow me to input the list of email addresses in the script called email.php, but I have no idea how to do this.

Like this:

[image: http://oi60.tinypic.com/261yhl3.jpg]

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Add Email Addresses...</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><textarea name="message" cols="50" rows="20"></textarea></td>

        </tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="left">
           <input type="submit" name="send" value="Add Email" style="height:35px; width:100px">
        </td>
    </table>
    </form>
    </body>
```

Here is the code for the email.php script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Send Email</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"  />
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="pr_send.php" method="POST">
    <table> 
        <!-- <tr>
            <td>From:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="from"></td>
        </tr> -->
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" name="to" value="" style="height:24px; width:24px; background:url('addressbook.png'); border:none;" onClick="Popup()"> To:</td> 
            <td><input type="text" name="to" style="height:15px; width:650px"></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Subject:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="subject" style="height:15px; width:650px"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Message:</td>
            <td><textarea name="message" cols="90" rows="20"></textarea></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            </br>
            <td colspan="2" align="left">
               <input type="submit" name="send" value="" style="height:35px; width:100px; background:url('send.png'); border:none">
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    </form>
    </body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Popup() 
{
  window.open("add_address.php", "_blank", "toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=100, left=500, width=400, height=400");
}
</script>

</html>
```

Here is the textbox that I want to output with a list of email addresses:

```
<td><input type="text" name="to" style="height:15px; width:650px"></td>
```

Can you please help me how I can extract a list of email addresses with a comma to output them in the textbox from the script add_address.php to my script called email.php?

Comment: Are you talking about the client or the server side? Also it is unclear where those addresses should come from. Please add those details to the question above using the `edit` button below the question. Do _not_ add them as a comment here. Thanks!

Comment: @arkascha please see the picture in my question that I have updated. I want to achieve by extract the list of email addresses that I have input in a message from a script called add_address.php to output the list of email addresses with a comma in the textbox of my script called email.php. Hope that is clear?

Comment: Your php script is another HTML form. I think you need to first understand how php works. You need to post the comma separated email addresses to an actual script that will send the email for you

Comment: If I get that right then the first image is a text input box where someone inputs the addresses. If so, then you have two options: server side or client side. In both cases you need a script. Client side would be javascript, server side might be php or any other suitable scripting language available on your http server. Then finally the second form has to be sent to the server again for processing, so sending out an email in this case. You cannot do that from the client side (at least that does not make sense...).

Comment: @arkascha I am using  a server side so is it possible to input a text from a text input box where some inputs the list of email addresses?

Comment: Yes sure, that is just a normal input field which you can send as an html form to the server. There a script can receive the text, prepare it however it wants to and output stuff again. A pre filled email form in this example. This certainly is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several assumptions in here and this really isn't the best way to approach things.

First you need to append the following line to the HTML in your `add_address.php` script just above the `<table>` tag:

```
<form action="email.php" method="post">
```

Without that line your form isn't going to submit anything anywhere when you click the button. The second thing to realise is that even doing this step means that your `email.php` page is going to open in the window you've open. Your submit, as it stands, is not going to update the `email.php` that you opened the window from.

That aside here's how you would then capture this.

Assuming that the data is going be email addresses on individual lines then you could do the following in `email.php` at the top of the page

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_POST['message'])) {
        $emails = explode("\n", $_POST['message']); // explode textarea on a line break into an array
        $email_str = implode(",", $emails); // take each of the emails and implode together with the ,
     }
?>
```

You could then refer to `$email_str` with an `echo`

```
<input type="text" name="to" value="<?php if (!empty($email_str)) { echo $email_str; } ?>">
```

That should take the content of the textarea and transpose it to a comma separated string.

Comment: yes you are almost correct, I have input a list of arrays in the message in each line when I run the script called `add_aaddress.php`. When I click on the button, I want to add each email address with a comma to output them in the textbox in the script called email.php. I got a huge list of email addresses so it will be impossible for me to write a list of variables to allowed me to output for these email addresses. You should change your code to allowed me to output each different email addresses.

Comment: The top snippet of code in your question is that the `add_address.php` file? I can see a closing tag for a `</form>` but no opening tag?

When you click the submit button are you expecting it to POST somewhere?

Comment: yes it is, the top snippet is the `add_address.php` file. Yes i ma expecting it to POST somewhere when I click on the submit button. Can you help?

Comment: What file are you expecting it to POST to?

You need to have a `<form>` tag around any elements you want to POST, it'll need to contain two attributes a `method` which in your case will be `POST` and an `action` which would be the file you want it to POST to.

Currently your top snippet is missing that.

Comment: I am expecting to POST it to `email.php` from `add_address.php`. If you can help that would be great.

Comment: Cool so you'll need to add to the `address_address.php` the `<form>` tag as explained above (would be good to update your question to show this)

Could you also provide the contents of the email.php file?

Comment: I have already updated the full code for the email.php which is on the second snippet below the first one.

Comment: thank you very much for this, in which line I need to input this code `<input type="text" name="to" value="<?php if (!empty($email_str)) { echo $email_str; } ?>">` and in which file?

Comment: Looking at that line and following the code that is going to output the comma separated list of emails, so you need to place that when you want to see that result.

It's a direct replace of the "to" address on the email.php file.

Comment: thank you very much for that. When I click on the submit button to open the popup, when I input the email addresses in the text input box and when I click on the submit button, how I can close on the small popup to allow me to input the email addresses in the textbox?

Comment: You'll have to ask that as a separate question on here. Look into how you made the dialog window open in the first place and maybe search for a way to close it.